# Routing failure on a multihomed Devuan laptop when ethernet cable removed and wifi connection active

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, ethernet

I have a Devuan Chimaera laptop (GNU/Linux, based off Debian) that has ethernet and wifi connectivity. When I connect to the wifi and take out the ethernet cable, I expect packets to no longer be routed out the ethernet port, and to go via wifi (which works fine when used alone).

This isn't what happens - in order to ping 1.1.1.1, I have to bind ping to the wifi adapter - checking 'ip route list' shows the following:

```
default via 192.168.188.1 dev wlxb8b7f1d4cb8f proto dhcp metric 600
192.168.188.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.188.33 linkdown
192.168.188.0/24 dev wlxb8b7f1d4cb8f proto kernel scope link src 192.168.188.34 metric 600
```

When I delete the default route over eth0 everything works. The kernel knows the link is down, so why is it routing packets over the dead interface?

For reference I'm using network-manager-gnome 1.20.0-3.

Answer (score 0):

I'll ignore any interference from NetworkManager here. This assumption might be wrong, considering there would probably be two default routes with different metrics rather than OP's single one, so additional integration with such tool might still be needed. If the toggle present below disappears, it can probably be enabled back by using a script somewhere in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispacher.d/`. Here's the [relevant documentation](https://networkmanager.dev/docs/api/latest/NetworkManager-dispatcher.html) or man page: [`NetworkManager-dispatcher(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/network-manager/NetworkManager-dispatcher.8.en.html) (the man page might not have been available in the past but the feature was) but I won't address this part.

One can solve this very simply by toggling the interface property [`ignore_routes_with_linkdown`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v5.15#n1658) to change the route evaluation:

> ignore_routes_with_linkdown - BOOLEAN
>      **Ignore routes whose link is down** when performing a FIB lookup.

This toggle has been available since [Linux kernel 4.2](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.2#Networking).

Before:

> ```
> default via 192.168.188.1 dev wlxb8b7f1d4cb8f proto dhcp metric 600
> 192.168.188.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.188.33 linkdown
> 192.168.188.0/24 dev wlxb8b7f1d4cb8f proto kernel scope link src 192.168.188.34 metric 600
> ```

```
$ ip route get 192.168.188.1
192.168.188.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.188.33 uid 1000 
    cache
```

Here the default gateway is still reached on `eth0`, meaning ARP requests to find it will likely go through `eth0` too, while it should be reached on (and ARP queried on) `wlxb8b7f1d4cb8f`. This kind of asymmetric routing prevents correct connectivity.

Toggle setting (to be adequately used in `/etc/sysctl.conf` or in a file in `/etc/sysctl.d/`):

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.ignore_routes_with_linkdown=1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 1
```

After:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.188.1 dev wlxb8b7f1d4cb8f proto dhcp metric 600 
192.168.188.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.188.33 dead linkdown 
192.168.188.0/24 dev wlxb8b7f1d4cb8f proto kernel scope link src 192.168.188.34 metric 600
```

The route on `eth0` now gets an additional property `dead` in addition to `linkdown` meaning it will be ignored in route lookups.

```
$ ip route get 192.168.188.1
192.168.188.1 dev wlxb8b7f1d4cb8f src 192.168.188.34 uid 1000 
    cache
```

Now the correct interface is chosen to use the gateway 192.168.188.1 to reach Internet.

---

Note: as it appears that the very same LAN is available on both interfaces, an entirely different approach that could be considered is to use [bonding](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.rst) with both interfaces in active-backup mode. Wireless doesn't prevent such use (it only prevents bridging for the client), but a few configuration tweaks would probably be needed (eg: changing the default handling of the MAC address on the bonding interface, and this could interfere with DHCP).